# Help convert this charging indicator circuit

Tags: batteries, diodes, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I have found [this](http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/battery-charging-indicator-circuit.jpg) schematic to track when a battery is being charged, but I don't know how to convert it to work with a different voltage.
The charging voltage is 25.2V and the lowest the battery can go is 22.2V. I want to charge it with up to 2 amps.

I am not very good at electronics and the best I can do is change the resistors values, but I have no idea about the diodes or the comparator.
Thank you for your help in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuit appears to trigger when it sees current flowing into the battery, with the 1M resistor only being there to create an offset to keep it switched off at 0 current, (op amp input offset voltage)

To make this circuit work on a higher voltage you should only need to increase the LED resistor value, to about 4.7K, and reduce it back if the brightness is too low for you.

The op amp is rated to run up to 36V, so your still in its specs

edit: R3 can likely be reduced in value and still work.

Comment: Thank you so much!